# How do I integrate java script into html?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to know how my code could be displayed on a webpage instead of displayed in alert boxes, how do I do this. I understand that id's ect are needed but I am a little confused of where to start. Any help would be good. Thankyou!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<script>



//Set of variables
var nameCheck = /^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/;
//eliminates anything not relevant
var numberCheck = /^[0-9\.]+$/;
//eliminates anything not relevant
var totHours = 0;
//adds total gaming hours on one day
var dayHours = 0;
//how many on one such day set in i from 1-7
var averHours = 0;
//stores the average by dividing by the tothours by 7
var mostPerDay = 0;
//calculates day with most gamed
var mostOnDay = 0;
//Most hours on ONE day
var moreDays = " ";
//adds an s to the end of days if more than one
var mpd = 0;
//most per day
var ah = 0;
//average hours
var th = 0;
//total hours
var name = prompt("What is your name?");
//asks users name


//Make sure user inputs a name that includes letters and or spaces
while (name == "null" || isNaN(name) == false || !name.match(nameCheck)){
 alert("Invalid Name!");
 name = prompt("What is your name?");
}

//Greets the user by name
alert("Hello " + name );

//Ask how many hours gamed on a day
for (var i = 1; i <= 7; i++){
 dayHours = prompt("How many hours have you gamed on day " + i + "?")

//Reask the question if the user inputs an invald answer
 while (dayHours == null || isNaN(dayHours) || dayHours > 24 || !dayHours.match(numberCheck) || dayHours < 0){
  alert("Incorrect! No letters or symbols, and make sure your input is under 24");
  dayHours = prompt("How many hours have you gamed on day " + i + "?")
 }

//Adds to total hours
totHours += Number(dayHours)
//Calculates days with most hours gamed
if (mostPerDay > dayHours){
}
else if (mostPerDay < dayHours){
 mostPerDay = Number(dayHours);
 mostOnDay = i;
}
else if (mostPerDay = dayHours){
 mostOnDay += " and " + i;
 mostPerDay = Number(dayHours);
}

}
//Adds 's' to the statistics if more than one day
if (isNaN(mostOnDay) == true){
 moreDays = "s ";
}
//Divides the total hours by 7 to get average over those 7 days
aver = (totHours / 7);
//Calculates and rounds to the value of 1
th = totHours.toFixed(1);
ah = aver.toFixed(2);
mpd = mostPerDay.toFixed(1);

//States calculated statistics
alert("\nTotal gaming hours this week " + th + "\nAverage gaming hours this week " + ah + "\nMost on one day" + moreDays + mostOnDay + " for " + mpd + " hours." );

//Comments on average hours per day gamed

if (averHours <= 2){
alert("Healthy amount of gaming this week")
}
else if (averHours <= 24){
 alert("Unhealthy amount of gaming this week")
}



</script>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to include JavaScript in an HTML document:

- Put the JavaScript code in a separate `filename.js` document and refer to it in the header of the HTML document (that is, between `<head>` and `</head>`) as follows: `<script type="text/javascript" src="filename.js"></script>`. This is the "cleanest" option as it separates functionality (JavaScript) from structure (HTML).
- Put the JavaScript code directly in the header of the HTML document; that is, between `<script type="text/javascript">` and `</script>` (no `src` attribute here)
- In the body of the HTML document, again between `<script>` and `</script>`, for example when you want to dynamically add text with `document.write('');`

Changing the text in a `<div id="mydiv">` can be done by accessing it via its `id`:

```
document.getElementById('mydiv').innerText = 'text';
```

or through the variants `innerHTML`, `outerText` or `outerHTML`.

For easy DOM manipulation, you may want to look into jQuery. Also, keep in mind that the JavaScript code in the header or external file will be executed immediately, which may cause errors if certain parts of the document body aren't loaded yet. jQuery offers an elegant solution by wrapping the code in

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // code here
});
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

A simple method to do this would be to include a link to an external javascript file:

```
<script src="path/myfile.js"></script>
```

at the bottom of your html file. If your script requires jQuery, make sure it is linked as an external script before your script. You can reference html elements in your javascript file by giving your html tags an id or class. For example:

In HTML:

```
<div id = "mydiv"> </div>
```

Select element in JS:

```
$('#mydiv')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to make your web page more reactive, you may want to look into jquery. It's a lightweight javascript library that can help you make your web page more interactive. Check out the tutorial below:

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/

I don't entirely understand your question, but just in case you are asking if the javascript will literally show up on your web page, it won't unless you display it as text. If you want to debug your javascript code, you can use developer tools on Chrome or something like it on other browsers:

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools